# Shorten the web URL

Tags: web-development

I am using a webapplication using simple jsp's, servlet and Struts. I am using Jetty 6.1.26 as a webserver. Is it possible for me to shorten the url that i have. For e.g.

I know that i will always be using http://hostname:port/webappname in the begining of each and every resource that i would be accessing.

is it possible for me to just type webappname in the browser address and that will take me to above location?

I think it might be possible by bookmark? but i dont want my each and every client to bookmark page. Is it possible to do above. I was looking at forum and i think proxyPass does something similar? If it is then can someone guide me though how i can use it and if any sample examples would be helpful?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use port 80 instead of some other port you can ommit the port at all. As 80 is the default http port.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read in the Jetty documentation on Virtual Hosts

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Virtual+hosts